# Is there anyway to clean/normalise this mesh

Tags: model, 3d, blender

I've been handed some off the shelf meshes to use and I'm finding a number of them have really dirty geometry which is causing an issue with rendering them in (three.js).

Screen shot of the geometry mesh can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si6tO.png actual mesh can be downloaded here http://just.dabe.co.uk/dump/three/model/iphone4.obj

The problem is when using THREE.SmoothShading the bad geometry shows up. Is there a tool that can normalise/fix a mesh so the polys are equally spaced etc?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but about 3D modeling.

Comment: I voted to close your question because Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not for questions about resources for programming tools. I think the http://threejs.org/ site would be a better place for this question - you'll likely find more knowledgable people there.

Comment: Okay, thanks - the reason I was asking here is because it related to three.js. No worries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use disolve faces. Select faces you want to join an pres x and then select disolve faces. You can also select limited disolve (in the delete menu). That vill joun all the selected faces eic have similar angle. You can also range the angle in which the faces will be joining.

Comment: Thank you Roki, Your solution would work so I will mark your answer as accepted as there are no others. I followed the advice in the comments above and asked this question on the Blender community. For any others looking for the answer check out http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/is-there-any-way-to-clean-a-triangulated-mesh